# Getting Consul and Registrator to work in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, consul, registrator

I'm trying to use `Consul` with `Registrator` in GCE & K8s. Everything launches fine except `Registrator'.

Here is my deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: consul
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        service: consul
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        - name: consul
          image: eu.gcr.io/xxx/consul
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8300
            protocol: TCP
          - containerPort: 8400
            protocol: TCP
          - containerPort: 8500
            protocol: TCP
          - containerPort: 53
            protocol: UDP
          env:
            - name: MY_POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
          args:
            - -server
            - -bootstrap
            - -advertise=$(MY_POD_IP)

        - name: registrator
          args:
            - -internal
            - -ip=$(MY_POD_IP)
            - consul://localhost:8500
          env:
            - name: MY_POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
          image: eu.gcr.io/xxx/registrator
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /tmp/docker.sock
              name: registrator-claim0
      volumes:
        - name: registrator-claim0 
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: registrator-claim0
status: {}
```

Here are the log outputs:
Consul:
[image]
Registrator:
[image]

In docker-compose everything works fine, but I haven't got my head completeley around K8s and GCE. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you explain why you prefer consul/registrator instead of the built-in Pod Labels / Service Label Queries and Endpoints for service discovery?

Kubernetes is different from Compose in that it provides integrated ways to discover and load balance your deployments

Comment: Inside my apps I use the consul api to query the hosts and ports of other apps they have to communicate with. I know K8s uses etcd, but I haven't used it yet.

Comment: with k8s you don't talk with etcd directly, you have a services API (but it's abstracted using DNS). It's also pluggable, so you could use Linkerd or anything else. There must be k8s controllers for consul as well (so you don't need registrator)

Comment: thank you. Getting my head around linkerd. Seems pretty cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have switched to Linkerd which works very well together with k8s.

Comment: sweet, link up a blog post if you have time to write down your experience with it :D